# How to load an image in prepareForInterfaceBuilder with a IBDesignable UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift

I would like to load a sample image in an IB designable `UIImageView`, to be shown in Interface Builder while editing the interface. The following code does not work, as the view placeholder in IB remains empty (the view area contains only the UIImageView text):

```
@IBDesignable
class TestImageView : UIImageView
{
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        //let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: nil)
        let imagePath = bundle.pathForResource("Test", ofType: "jpg")
        self.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
    }
}
```

Note that:

- in IB the Custom Class class for the view is correct (TestImageView)
- Test.jpg is present in the project (if I manually set the image property of the `UIImageView` in IB the image shows up).
- I tried the two different methods of getting the bundle present in the code

This was tested with Xcode 6 beta 3.

**Update**: in both cases the bundle path I get is `"/Applications/Temporary/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays"`. In that path the image is obviously not present.

Comment: posted a radar to apple rdar://17762946

Comment: say, shouldn't you be calling super in prepareForInterfaceBuilder ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Updated for Swift 4.2

When you instantiate an UIImage (with UIImage(named : "SomeName") the app will look for the asset in your **main bundle**, which works fine usually. But when you are at *design time*, the InterfaceBuilder holds the code of the designable views (for *compiling* while *designing*) in a separate bundle.

So the solution is: Define your **bundle dynamically**, hence your files can be found in design, compile and run time:

```
    // DYNAMIC BUNDLE DEFINITION FOR DESIGNABLE CLASS
    let dynamicBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))

    // OR ALTERNATIVELY BY PROVDING THE CONCRETE NAME OF YOUR DESIGNABLE VIEW CLASS
    let dynamicBundle = Bundle(for: YourDesignableView.self)

    // AND THEN SUCCESSFULLY YOU CAN LOAD THE RESSOURCE
    let image = UIImage(named: "Logo", in: dynamicBundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

Comment: You're a hero for that one.  Why does it need this though?

Comment: @ScottyBlades: When you run your app, all code files to be compiled, are usually in the main bundle. But when you are at design time, the InterfaceBuilder holds the code of the designable views (for compiling *while designing*) in a separate bundle.

Comment: How do you do this in Interface Builder? I tried using the "Bundle_name/image_name" in the UIImageView but it didn't work.

Answer (score 53):

Try getting the bundle of the class like this:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
```

or specifying the class name like this

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: TestImageView.self)
```

Assuming that your image is in the bundle, for example Images.xcassets, you can then load it using:

```
self.image = UIImage("Test", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: self.traitCollection)
```

Remember to check whether your image is nil before trying to use it. I have not been able to get the image path using bundle.pathForResource to work correctly with normal image assets. There also doesn't appear to be a UIImage call where you specify just the name and bundle, so you have to use trait collection.

This question is related to:

[xcode 6 IB_DESIGNABLE- not loading resources from bundle in Interface builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603232/xcode-6-ib-designable-not-loading-resources-from-bundle-in-interface-builder/24770557#24770557)

Response from Apple...

> Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based
>   on the following:
>
> We can't really make this any easier than specifying the bundle. You
>   might say, "oh, let's swizzle -[NSBundle mainBundle]", but lots of
>   call sites that reference a bundle don't go through there (or go
>   through the CF API). One might say then "ok, well then how about we at
>   least swizzle -[UIImage imageNamed:]". The problem here is that there
>   is no single replacement for the main bundle. You might have multiple
>   live view bundles (either frameworks or apps) loaded in at once, so we
>   can't just pick one to be the main bundle.
>
> Developers need to be aware of bundles and how to get images from a
>   bundle. Developers should be using
>   UIImage(named:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:) for all image lookups.

Comment: thx for answering, but the correct way to do that should be the one described in my own answer.

Comment: I provided the bundle example because I had posted a bug report (17656550) to Apple about being unable to find resources in Live View. I added the response from Apple to my answer.

Comment: Great investigation, apparently you have to be very aware of the "scope" in which views live when they get rendered as a Live View.

Comment: This is noted in the Xcode 9 release notes (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW878) as a known issue: "Using a Swift image literal within prepareForInterfaceBuilder() causes IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch to crash because live views are compiled in a different bundle. (28676479)
Workaround: Use UIImage(named:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:) for all image lookups, and use Bundle(for: type(of: self)) to find the bundle for the live view class."

Answer (score 7):

Lets pop in the swift 3 answer

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)
... UIImage(named: "AnImageInYourAssetsFolderPerhaps", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)!
```

Answer (score 6):

*For Swift 4 (and 3) use this:*

```
let image = UIImage(named: "foo", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: traitCollection)
```

This approach gets the bundle universally

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix the issue getting the Interface Builder project path from the current `NSProcessInfo`object. You can then gather the correct path from the `IB_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIRECTORIES`key.

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    let processInfo = NSProcessInfo.processInfo()
    let environment = processInfo.environment
    let projectSourceDirectories : AnyObject = environment["IB_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIRECTORIES"]!
    let directories = projectSourceDirectories.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

    if directories.count != 0 {
        let firstPath = directories[0] as String
        let imagePath = firstPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("PrepareForIBTest/Test.jpg")

        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

This technique is described in the WWDC 2014 411 session "What's New in Interface Builder" as suggested by bjhomer in this [Apple Developer Forums post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1002168).

Moreover, I need to say that **it was required to switch to a `UIView` subclass**, because it seems that the appereance of the `UIImageView`does not change in live views.

Comment: Appears to me that the correct response is either #kasplat in this post or @rickster on that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603232/xcode-6-ib-designable-not-loading-resources-from-bundle-in-interface-builder

Comment: I was accepting this answer because it is based on a WWDC session, so it appeared to me like an official information from Apple. What do you think?

Comment: It seems that Apple now provides a simpler approach: `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` can only takes you so far, and requires very specific action. `NSBundle:forClass` on the other hand is nimble and well encapsulated. Maybe Apple is now providing a better, more lightweight solution in response to bug (17656550)?

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 2 and Xcode 7, the interface has been changed. Should use

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: self.traitCollection)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

I use it in [my project](https://github.com/JakeLin/IBAnimatable/blob/master/IBAnimatable/SideImageDesignable.swift#L36), it works fine for both IB and device.

Comment: Thanks. However I do not get how it is different to @kasplat answer.

Comment: The init of UIImage is different.

Answer (score 0):

This will load your IB_Designable, or if you have none - the default image.

```
- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    imagePic = imagePic ? [imagePic imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"goodIcon" inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:self.traitCollection];

}
```