# How to show image on custom button control in designer

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I have a custom button control where I am trying to show an image for the button but it is not appearing despite defining it programatically.

```
@IBDesignable class UCButtonNext: UIButton {
    // setup programatically
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButton()
    }

    // setup via Storyboard
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupButton()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupButton()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupButton()
    }

    func setupButton() {
        setupButtonStyle()
        setupShadow()
    }

    func setupButtonStyle() {
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)

        backgroundColor         = UIColor.clear
        titleLabel?.font        = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 18)
        setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

        layer.cornerRadius      = frame.height / 2
        layer.borderWidth       = 1.0
        layer.borderColor       = UIColor.white.cgColor

        setImage(UIImage(named: "btnArrowRight"), for: .normal)
    }
```

My button shows in designer but can't seem to get the image to show.

[image]

Comment: It seems that everything works except setting the image, so I'd check the project to see that the image exists and was imported properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer Alex pointed you to - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40359161/10657724 - should be what you need.

To help you debug the problem, change this line:

```
setImage(UIImage(named: "btnArrowRight"), for: .normal)
```

to:

```
    // DYNAMIC BUNDLE DEFINITION FOR DESIGNABLE CLASS
    let dynamicBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))

    // AND THEN SUCCESSFULLY YOU CAN LOAD THE RESSOURCE
    if let image = UIImage(named: "btnArrowRight", in: dynamicBundle, compatibleWith: nil) {
        setImage(image, for: .normal)
        setTitle("Works!", for: .normal)
    } else {
        setTitle("Failed!", for: .normal)
    }
```

That will set the title of your button to either "Works!" or "Failed!"

If you see "Works!" you should also see your image.

Otherwise, you've got something wrong with your image resource.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question may help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40359161/10657724

You need to specify the bundle dynamically when creating the image as the main bundle is not available at design time.

Comment: I've tried both from this example but neither seems to work. Also, the image does not show in simulator mode or on phone in run mode. '// Tried this // let image = UIImage(named: "btnArrowRight", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: traitCollection) // setImage(image, for: .normal) // Tried this // let dynamicBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self)) // let image = UIImage(named: "btnArrowRight", in: dynamicBundle, compatibleWith: nil) // setImage(image, for: .normal)'