# Xcode - is it possible to debug crashes in the Interface Builder's Live Rendering process (IBDesignable)?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder

**Question**

Is it possible to set breakpoints and debug code executed by Xcode / Interface Builder's Live Rendering?  That is, I am using the IBDesignable and IBInspectable attributes to affect the view as it is rendered in an interface builder storyboard, and would like to be able to debug "IB crashed" errors.  I don't recall this from the WWDC session, other than the section on prepareForInterfaceBuilder.

**Context**

I recently started seeing a number of errors reporting that IB crashed when attempting to render my code.  I ultimately traced it to an otherwise innocent line of code in layoutSubviews in one of my views that was linked from the storyboard.  The specific problem that IB - when rendering live views, called layoutSubviews before setting all the view's child view properties (which seems like a separate problem, in and of itself).  This contrasted with the simulator and device, in which the views were set ahead of the first call to layoutSubviews.  Long story short though, it involved diffing a bunch of files to find the offending change.  Suffice to say, I could have found the problem quickly if it were possible to set breakpoints and trap the crash.

Has anyone figured out how to debug and/or generally trap these problems, or is that access not yet available?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I watched the WWDC video again (§411 @22:00 or so).  You have to

- edit a view in IB, and set its custom class to a class in your codebase
- set breakpoints as desired in your custom class
- select the view in IB, then select Editor -> "Debug Selected Views" (at bottom)

Oddly, in my tests today, it is creating my view via (initWith)Frame instead of (initWith)Coder.  This causes subsequent constraint configuration logic to fail as the sub views have not been set (as they would had 'withCoder been called).

Comment: "This causes subsequent constraint configuration logic to fail as the sub views have not been set (as they would had 'withCoder been called)." How did you fix it?

Comment: @MartijnHols:  When you use IBDesignable, you have to create the views entirely from initWithFrame (via helper function etc), you cannot use views set from the Xib, even though it works in the app.  It ends up being better for drawing sub views, then laying out larger views. In my view, IBDesignable should be implemented via initWithCoder etc, instead of initWithFrame.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use a Xib so that wasn't applicable and all views are available. What I did while the storyboard was crashing was using the original UIView's `frame` to position my subviews while also adding some constraints to some of these subviews. Because the storyboard initializes the UIView with a `CGRectZero` this messed up some sizes which in turn broke the constraints (probably ending up in an endless loop freezing the storyboard). I ended up fixing my issues by removing all `frame` usages and only using constraints instead. Bit more complicated in code, but fixes the issue.

Answer (score 9):

(tools note: Xcode 8.2, macOS Sierra)

I had a very different failure than yours: I had a crash in code that resulted in an IB error in Xcode:

> error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent crashed

To debug this on macOS Sierra, open Console.app, and open "User Reports" in the right sidebar. Find the "IBDesignablesCocoaTouch*" crashes, and select the applicable one. This gave me the code-level info I needed to diagnose it.

```
Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 375.21 - Device: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x - Runtime: iOS 10.3 (14E8301) - DeviceType: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftUIKit.dylib             0x000000021a2ddead _TToFE5UIKitCSo7UIImagecfT24imageLiteralResourceNameSS_S0_ + 205
1   libswiftUIKit.dylib             0x000000021a2ddcef _TFE5UIKitCSo7UIImageCfT24imageLiteralResourceNameSS_S0_ + 79
2   com.company.App         0x0000000216df74ad _TZFC10App21ControlsP33_F7118662B6663018C7DD0DEBB6FDD87511buttonImagefT8forStateOS_25State_CSo7UIImage + 109 (Controls.swift:121)
…
```

(In my case, Interface Builder was failing to load an image literal. I had to implement this workaround: [xcode 6 IB_DESIGNABLE- not loading resources from bundle in Interface builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603232/xcode-6-ib-designable-not-loading-resources-from-bundle-in-interface-builder))

Comment: This should be one of the top comments for sure. Awesome! In the latest Xcode (11) I can't seem to get the view debugging working at all, but going into console and checking (now Crash Reports) was gold! Thank you!