# IBInspectable and NSLocalizedString

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, xcode6

I have a lot of localized texts written in my Localizable.strings file, and I am looking for a way to  use these and get them shown in the interface builder. That is, instead of creating outlets for all my views and setting the text in code, I would like to make an `IB_DESIGNABLE` UILabel subclass, which must access my Localizable.strings file and then show the localized text directly on the interface builder.

The problem is, that NSLocalizedString does not give any results in interface builder, but only when I actually *run* the code. Is there a way to tell the interface builder which file to use for localization (for example in prepareForInterfaceBuilder)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself. The answer is: use `[[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil]` to get translations from the Localizable.strings file in interface builder. This realization made it possible for me to redefine the `NSLocalizedString` macro (*only* for interface builder):

```
#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
#undef NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil]
#endif
```

Comment: BTW, thanks to @rickster for pointing the right direction in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603232/xcode-6-ib-designable-not-loading-resources-from-bundle-in-interface-builder#24604071)

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to JRV's answer I finally fixed this class:

```
@IBDesignable class ALLocalizableLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var localizeString:String = "" {
        didSet {
            #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
                var bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
                self.text = bundle.localizedStringForKey(self.localizeString, value:"", table: nil)
            #else
                self.text = NSLocalizedString(self.localizeString, comment:"");
            #endif
        }
    }

}
```

This creates the possibility to set the key in the interface builder:

[image: Localized string set in interface builder]

This will update the label directly in the interface builder, quite cool and something xcode should support by default!

You can find this on Github as well:
https://github.com/AvdLee/ALLocalizableLabel

Comment: This didn't work for me in the Interface Builder, until I included the `layoutSubviews` override. Could you explain why its needed?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class YourLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var stringLocalizationKey: String = ""{
        didSet{
            text = stringLocalizationKey.localized
            setup()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    }

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        self.text = bundle.localizedString(forKey: self.stringLocalizationKey, value:"", table: nil)
    }
}
```

And add this `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```