# Making outlet for the object from a xib file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I am having a Hint.xib file where I have few elements (label, image view and a button). And I have a class called Hint, which is the subclass of a UIView and which loads this xib.

Here is how Hint class implementation looks:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

extension UIView {
    class func fromNib<T : UIView>() -> T? {
        guard
            let nibs = Bundle(for: self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: self), owner: nil, options: nil),
            let nib = nibs.first
            else {
                return nil
        }

        return nib as? T
    }
}

class Hint:UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var hintLabel: UILabel! 
    private func setup(){

        if let view = Hint.fromNib(){
            self.addSubview(view)
            view.frame = self.bounds
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }


    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

       setup()
    }
}
```

**Current Setup**

On a storyboard, currently, I've added one view controller, and I have dragged a UIView inside of that view controller's view. After that, I set its custom class to `Hint`. Also I am using `@IBDesignable` directive and have overriden `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` to have everything rendered in design, and this all works until I try to make an outlet for a label (`hintLabel`) that is a part of a Hint.xib file.

I am getting next error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[< NSObject 0x60000001f8a0 > setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hintLabel.'

I've selected my Hint.xib file -> File's Owner, and checked if everything is okay in Identity Inspector, and it seems things are fine there:

[image]

What would be an appropriate way to change this label's text either through IB or through the code. Also, I can't just change this label's text in Hint.xib, because I might to have multiple views on a screen that load (from) this xib and all of those views should have different text. I think I am missing something obvious here...Thanks for your hints :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is very close to working. The problem is you need to set the owner to the hint view, but you're trying to do that in a class method. `self` in a class method is the class, whereas you need `self` to be the *instance* of the class. Your `fromNib` method doesn't need to be a class method, it can be an instance method. Here's an example:

```
extension UIView {
    func createView<T : UIView>() -> T? {
        let type = type(of:self)
        guard
            let nibs = Bundle(for: type).loadNibNamed(String(describing: type), owner: self, options: nil),
            let nib = nibs.last
            else {
                return nil
        }

        return nib as? T
    }
}
```

Now in your view setup, you can use `if let view = createView(){ //... }`.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was trying to achieve in the first place, no matter if it is a static or  instance method, the importance was on having it in extension on a UIView.

Comment: And for those who are interested in why loading from main bundle didn't work for live preview, but still working at runtime, take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24604071/3402095

Comment: Good answer Ben, nice piece of code. It works very well.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you have to load xib from bundle with "owner:self" so it should look like this:

```
class Hint:UIView {
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var hintLabel: UILabel!
    private func setup(){

        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Hint", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }


    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to set File Owner to Hint class in xib file (not UIView)

Comment: It didn't worked. I get the same error... Also, I am trying to achieve here few things : 1) To have a reusable xib. 2) To be able to *initialize* multiple views from it on a same view controller so that every view has a label with different text. 3) To have live preview at design time of all those views in a storyboard.

Comment: And about your suggestions, can you explain why do you suggest that? Can you be more precise ?

Comment: view is optional, you should cast it with `hintLabel = (view as! Hint).hintLabel`

Comment: @MücahitTekin Well, this worked partially - at runtime everything was okay, but at design time, live preview in storyboard was all messed up. But I fixed that by using ` if let hView = Bundle(for: Hint.self).loadNibNamed("Hint", owner: self, options: nil)?.first   {...` instead of a main bundle.